# how to store image / video file using gundb?

Tags: javascript, gun, gundb

I know the traditional way is to store image/video file in one place and then just save the reference index into db's table.

Now I am learning about gundb, I can store key-value json type data very easily, but since it is decentralized, if I wanna make a say chatroom app, how should I handle image storing (eg: user's avatar)?

I am also wondering if it is possible to make a movie-sharing app using gundb?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@Retric, great question! I'm not sure why people are downvoting you, they must be haters.

You are right, it is better to store that image/video and reference it via GUN. For videos specifically, WebTorrent/BitTorrent has done P2P video sharing for over a decade now and at one point handled 40% of the world's internet traffic!

However WebTorrent/BitTorrent is not very good with discovering/sharing those URIs (magnet links, etc.) but GUN is. So I'd recommend that as one option.

For images, especially small ones like avatars/icons/profiles, I do often store them in GUN directly by `Base64` encoding them (many websites around the world inline images/icons/sprites/avatars into CSS files with base64 data-URLs, except now you could use GUN for this).

If you are interested in this, I wrote a small utility using jQuery that lets you drag&drop images into your website, and it'll auto-resize (pass options to overwrite it) and base64 encode it for you to then save to GUN:

https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/master/lib/upload.js

Here is a small example of how I use it:

```
$('#profile').upload(function resize(e, up){
    if(e.err){ return } // handle error
    $('#profile').addClass('pulse'); // css to indicate image processing
    if(up){ return up.shrink(e, resize, 64) } // pass it `e` drag&drop/upload event, then I reuse the current function (named resize) as the callback for it, and tell it resize to 64px.
    $('#profile').removeClass('pulse'); // css indicate done processing.
    $("#profile img").attr('src', e.base64).removeClass('none'); // set photo in HTML!
    gun.user().get('who').get('face').get('small').put(e.base64); // save profile thumbnail to GUN
});
```

Finally, what about storing videos in GUN if you don't want to use BitTorrent?

I would highly recommend using the HLS format to store videos in GUN, this would allow you to do decentralized realtime video streaming. It is a beautifully simple format that allows video streaming to work even from static files, because it stores the video in small chunks that can be streamed - which fits perfectly with GUN.

There already is a JS based video-player for the HLS format:

https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

Based off the demo page, you can see an example of how the video is stored, like here on GitHub:

https://github.com/video-dev/streams/tree/master/x36xhzz

(if you click on the m3u8 file, you'll see it has metadata that 720p is stored in `url_0` folder, which themselves have sub-files)

Rather than storing the HLS video files on BitTorrent or a centralized server, you could store it in GUN using the same folder structure `gun.get('videos').get('x36xhzz').get('url_0').get('url_496').get('193039199_mp4_h264_aac_hd_7.ts').once(function(video_chunk){ passToHLSplayer(video_chunk) })` such that it would be easy for HLS.js to integrate with GUN.

Now you'll have P2P decentralized video streaming!!!

And even cooler, you can combine it with GUN's `lib/webrtc` adapter and do this fully browser to browser!

I hope this helped.

Comment: thanks, it helps a lot! will check the HLS format, and the Base64 way for storing avatar is actually quite convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to understand here is the difference between [content addressed space (frozen space) and user space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72026649/1461850) in gun.

Let's say you have some media encoded as base64, and you know its content type (I've used text here to keep example short, but you could use image video etc):

```
// put avatar in frozen space:
let media = JSON.stringify({ b64 : "U2hlIHdhcyBib3JuIGFuIGFkdmVudHVyZXIuLi4=", type : "text/plain"})
// get hash of stringified media obj using gun's SEA lib:
let mediaID = await SEA.work(media, null, null, {name: "SHA-256"});
// put media in hash-addressed gundb
gun.get('#').get(mediaID).put(media,(r)=>console.log('Media put acknowledged?',r))
```

For a hypothetical chat app, you could use `user space` and put the media under the "avatar" name:

```
// put avatar in user space:
let user = await SEA.pair();
await gun.user().auth(user) 
gun.get('~' + user.pub).get('avatar').put('#' + mediaID)

// retrieve a user's avatar
gun.get('~' + usera.pub).get('avatar').once((hashid,k)=>{
    gun.get('#').get(hashid).once(media=>{
      console.log("Got user's avatar :-)",media)
      //do something with media
    })
})
```